# Rosmake missing error messages

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Often rosmake does not tell me what the error is when it finds an error.
In this case I am in the middle of converting an AtlasState variable to the new format, and it still has a .imu and .force_torque_sensors field. Here is the feedback from rosmake:

```
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc:1718:25: warning: ‘sensor_msgs::CvBridge::CvBridge()’ is deprecated (declared at /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:64) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc:1717:7: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc:1719:14: warning: unused variable ‘count’ [-Wunused-variable]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc:1720:7: warning: unused variable ‘ix’ [-Wunused-variable]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc:1720:11: warning: unused variable ‘iy’ [-Wunused-variable]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc:1720:15: warning: unused variable ‘index’ [-Wunused-variable]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc:1720:22: warning: unused variable ‘index2’ [-Wunused-variable]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc:1721:8: warning: unused variable ‘filename’ [-Wunused-variable]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc: In function ‘void imageCallbackRight(const ImageConstPtr&)’:
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc:1782:25: warning: ‘sensor_msgs::CvBridge::CvBridge()’ is deprecated (declared at /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:64) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc:1781:7: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc:1783:14: warning: unused variable ‘count’ [-Wunused-variable]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc:1784:7: warning: unused variable ‘ix’ [-Wunused-variable]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc:1784:11: warning: unused variable ‘iy’ [-Wunused-variable]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc:1784:15: warning: unused variable ‘index’ [-Wunused-variable]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc:1784:22: warning: unused variable ‘index2’ [-Wunused-variable]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc:1785:8: warning: unused variable ‘filename’ [-Wunused-variable]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc: In function ‘void DisparityCallback(const ConstPtr&)’:
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc:1843:7: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc: In function ‘void Points2Callback(const ConstPtr&)’:
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc:1877:37: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc:1880:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc:2098:7: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/atlas.h: At global scope:
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/atlas.h:117:20: warning: ‘joint_names’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/atlas.h:134:20: warning: ‘link_names’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/atlas.h:151:15: warning: ‘joint_offset’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/atlas.h:185:15: warning: ‘axis’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/atlas.h:219:15: warning: ‘com_offset’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/atlas.h:253:15: warning: ‘masses’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc:208:22: warning: ‘my_left_image’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
  /home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/main.cc:209:22: warning: ‘my_right_image’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/stand.dir/main.o] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/stand.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/cga/rosf/pkgs/rstand1/build'
```

I did get messages about the joint-states field not being defined.
After removing the .imu and .force_torque_sensors fields, I get no errors.

This happens fairly often, and I have to do a lot of detective work to figure out what the error is.
As you can imagine, it is a little difficult developing code with erratic feedback on compiler errors.
Any suggestions on how to deal with this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2404/rosmake-missing-error-messages/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2013-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

By default, `rosmake` only shows you the last 40 lines of compiler/linker output in error cases.

Two suggestions, in my preference order:

1. Call `make` explicitly on the (first) package that's failing to build.  E.g., instead of `rosmake rstand1`, do:

   ```
    roscd rstand1
    make
   ```

Then you'll get all the output.  If you want to see the compile and link lines (by default CMake hides them from you), do:

```
    roscd rstand1
    make VERBOSE=1
```

In addition to giving you all the build output, calling `make` on one package is faster than calling `rosmake`, because it doesn't try to build other packages.

1. Go look at the logs that `rosmake` produces.  At the end of each failed run, `rosmake` will say something like the following:

   ```
    [ rosmake ] Output from build of package joint_commands_gui written to:
    [ rosmake ]    /home/gerkey/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130416-110752/joint_commands_gui/build_output.log
   ```

The `build_output.log` file it's pointing to will have the complete output from `make`.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2